# Run a task every 30 seconds in Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I want a Nodejs application running on Heroku to run a task every 30 seconds. I use Heroku scheduler for another task but that's because it runs once a day and Scheduler seems fine for that, but to run at this interval it is not suitable.

So I have installed `node-cron` and setup a job that would run every 30 seconds, daily, between 11am and 6pm (I am basically calling an api and then updating a database), locally I can run this fine with `node cron.js`

*cron.js*

```
const cron = require('node-cron');
const task = require('./scripts/task');

cron.schedule('*/30 * 11-18 * * *', () => {
  console.log('Running Function');
  task.runFunction();
});
```

I'm not 100% sure how to run this on Heroku, from their [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes#custom-clock-processes) they specify this kind of setup (configured in Procfile):

```
web:    node web.js
worker: node worker.js
clock:  node clock.js
```

Current Procfile

```
web: node server.js
```

Is it a case of changing my `cron.js` to `clock.js` ? and then having something in a `worker.js` file? (though unsure as to what).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably change the clock.js to cron.js, or, as you say, rename cron.js to clock.js.

```
web:    node web.js
worker: node worker.js
clock:  node cron.js
```

Also, I'm not sure your cron.js is set up correctly. From the documentation on node-cron, it looks like you might need something that looks like this:

```
const CronJob = require('../lib/cron.js').CronJob;

console.log('Before job instantiation');`
const job = new CronJob('*/30 * 11-18 * * *', () => {
  console.log('Running Function');
  task.runFunction();
});
console.log('After job instantiation');
job.start();
```

Comment: Thank you, took me a while to get it, but working as wanted, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this line `worker: node worker.js` if in your `cron.js` you don't tell him to do somethings with this worker. (I don't know what `runFunctions()` do). And you don't even need to add the first line if your application is just cron jobs.
So you can just have this Profile :

```
clock: cron.js
```

You can change `clock`to `cron` if you want. It doesn't mean: [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-format).